# training = False in Keras Sequential API

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

We can pass the `training = False` argument while calling the pre-trained model when using Keras Functional API as shown in [this](https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/#transfer-learning-amp-finetuning) tutorial.

How to implement the same in Keras Sequential API?

Here's the code which I am trying to replicate using Sequential API:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input( shape = ( TARGET_SIZE[0], TARGET_SIZE[1], 3 ) )
base_model = Xception( include_top = False, pooling = 'avg' )
base_model.trainable = False
x = base_model( inputs, training = False ) 
x = Dense( 512, activation = 'relu' )( x )
x = Dense( 256, activation = 'relu' )( x )
x = Dense( 128, activation = 'relu' )( x )
outputs = Dense( 6, activation = 'softmax' )( x )
```

Below is the code implementing this whole model *without* `training = False` using Sequential API like below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add( Xception( include_top = False, pooling = 'avg', input_shape = ( TARGET_SIZE[0], TARGET_SIZE[1], 3 ) ) )
model.add( Dense( units = 512, activation = 'relu' ) )
model.add( Dense( units = 256, activation = 'relu' ) )
model.add( Dense( units = 128, activation = 'relu' ) )
model.add( Dense( 6, activation = 'softmax' ) )
```

But, I am unable to squeeze in the `training = False` argument with it.

Comment: please add your code to the question

Comment: If you scroll down just a little, it will tell you everything about the `trainable` attribute https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/#freezing-layers-understanding-the-trainable-attribute

Comment: @Andrey Code Added.

@NicolasGervais The query is regarding `training` attribute rather `trainable`

Comment: @Mrityu `training=False` should be a default value

Comment: @Andrey  But if that is the case, then for eg. the BatchNormalization layer will always run in inference mode i.e. it won't update its mean and variance statistics. Apart from that, what if we want to set `training = True` in the Sequential model? How can  we do it?

Comment: @Mrityu `training` argument normally is used to make a layer behaving differently in training and evaluation. As far as I understand - it is not supposed to be different for the same model. E.g. - by adding `Dropout()` with `training=False` you are actually just removing this layer from your model. Could you give an example - when using `training=False` could make sense ?

Comment: @Andrey Please refer to this [link]( https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/#transfer-learning-amp-finetuning ) and see the reasoning given by them for `training = False` in end-to-end example of image classification and fine-tuning on cats v/s dogs dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following, it worked for me:

load any base model, include_top = False, then (as example):

```
 flat1 = Flatten()(base_model.layers[-1].output, training=False)
    
 class1 = Dense(5, activation='relu')(flat1)
    
 output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(class1) 

 model = Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was asking myself the same question. Unfortunately, I did not find a clear explanation. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/transfer_learning) there is the Tensorflow  guide about transfer learning. As you can see, you can use `training = False` only if you call the model or the layer. So I realized that you need to use the first code you have written.